# How to access SharePoint Custom list using webserivces

Tags: web-services

I have a custom list called "Custom" with Title, Description and Date Site columns. I want to access this custom list using Web Services. Can anyone provide the solution with step by step .

Thanks,
John.

Comment: John, we need some more information to answer your question. How are you trying to access the custom list? Using a console application?

Answer (score 2):

Is it SharePoint 2007 or 2010?

For 2010, use the REST interface
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx

For 2007, you will need to use list.asmx

What will you be using to access the list? C#, Java, Javascript, InfoPath, ... ?

Some examples:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/paulballard/archive/2005/05/08/Using-Data-From-SharePoint-2003-Lists.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arpans/archive/2007/07/24/sharepoint-web-service-example-grabbing-wiki-content.aspx
- http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2007/02/how-to-use-getlistitems-web-service.html

Answer (score 1):

Just read article on MSDN:

[Lists.GetListItems Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Scroll to bottom an you can find working example (Console application written in C# and VB). If you need more info write 'sharepoint list.asmx getlistitems' in Google (or Bing) and you can easily find ton of other articles.

Comment: Vedran,... I read the article and looked at the C# code. It all looks good and I can refernce almost everything except I don't seem have access to the GetListItems extension for Lists. I'm writing a stand alone console app to migrate libraries from one Sharepoint site to a completely different site. Any advice?

Comment: @Glenn - GetListItems is webservice method so you need reference to http://<Site>/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx. If you are in need of a single migration explore the backup/restore options. In other cases if migrating 2007 use webservices, if 2010 use COM and if 2013 use REST.